# What do i do that when i click on youtube icon it take me to www.google.com

Tags: javascript, html, jquery

Hello I want that when I click on YouTube icon it take me to Google.com but it don't I'm using JavaScript in this

**HTML**

```
<div class="yt" >
   <i class="fab fa-youtube fa-3x" onclick="youtube()" id="yt"  ></i>
</div>
```

**Js**

```
function youtube() {
      document.getElementById("yt").window.location.href = "www.google.com";
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Replace the code in your `youtube` function with this: `window.location.assign("https://www.youtube.com")`

The `window.location.assign()` method loads a new document

If it still doesn't work, make sure that your JavaScript, if in a separate file, is properly imported.

https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Location/assign

Comment: Another thing you could also do is just use the `a` tag

Answer (score 0):

```
document.getElementById("yt").addEventListener('click', () =>  window.open('https://google.com'))
```

and make sure the javascript is executed after the element is in the DOM.
or just:

```
<a href="https://google.com"><i class="fab fa-youtube fa-3x" id="yt"></i></a>
```

Comment: @Reyyan you have to make sure the javascript code is executed after the element is displayed on the page.

Comment: How yo check if it executing before icon display

Comment: This should to the trick: window.addEventListener('DOMContentLoaded', () =>document.getElementById('yt').addEventListener('click', () => window.open('https://google.com')));

Answer (score 0):

Simply embed event listener to you icon ,

once clicking set `location.href = "http://www.google.com";`

See below ssnipt :

```js
window.addEventListener("DOMContentLoaded", (event) => {

  document.getElementById("yt").addEventListener("click", function(e) {
    location.href = "https://stackoverflow.com/";
  })
})
```

```css
.fab {
  color: red;
  cursor: pointer;
}
```

```html
<link href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/font-awesome/5.15.2/css/all.min.css" rel="stylesheet" />
<i class="fab fa-youtube fa-3x" id="yt"></i>
```

using jquery :

```js
$(function(){

  $("#yt").on("click", function() {
  
    location.href = "https://stackoverflow.com/"
  })
})
```

```css
.fab {
  color:red;
  cursor:pointer;
  
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<link href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/font-awesome/5.15.2/css/all.min.css" rel="stylesheet" />
<i class="fab fa-youtube fa-3x" id="yt"></i>
```

Comment: just try the code as posted , remove all you code , like youtube function and so on . as you can see work on snippet perfectly